# Inner Join em 5 tabelas

Tags: mysql

Tenho as tabelas:

- reparaveis
- projetos
- contratos
- itens_contratados
- controle_contratos

Fiz essa Consulta:

```
Select
    a.qtd as quantidade_contratada,
    b.pn,
    c.numero_contrato,
    count(d.id_pn) qtd_executada,
    (a.qtd - count(d.id_pn)) saldo,
    e.projeto
FROM
    itens_contratados a
    LEFT JOIN reparaveis b ON a.id_pn = b.id_pn
    INNER JOIN contratos c ON a.id_contrato = c.id_contrato
    INNER JOIN controle_contratos d ON a.id_pn = d.id_pn
    INNER JOIN projetos e ON e.id_projeto = d.id_projeto and e.id_projeto = a.id_projeto
Where
    d.status <> 'Cancelada' and d.status <> 'Aguardando Cancelamento'
GROUP BY 
    b.pn, e.projeto DESC
```

Tenho como resultado o que preciso quando existe registro na tabela `controle_contratos`, porém necessito ainda que nessa consulta apareça também os `b.id_pn` (`b.pn` do `Group By`) que não aparecem na tabela `controle_contratos`, alguém sabe onde estou errando?

Comment: Qual é a relação entre as tabelas? Poderia postar o MER?

Comment: Djalma reparaveis tem o id_pn e pn  projeto id_projeto e projeto contratos id_contrato e numero_contrato a tabela itens_contratados tem id_pn id_projeto e id_contrato e a ultima tem id_pn, id_contrato, id_projeto  ficou confuso ficou confuso..... não sei como mostrar o MER por aqui

Comment: Eu quero que apareça os itens que não tem registro na tabela do left join, mas não aparecem... quero todos os itens_contratados, mesmo que não tenha ele relacionado na tebela controle_contratos